# SQL Express vs SQL CE, latency/lag

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce

Specifications say SQL CE runs as an "in-memory-process". What does that really mean, and what is the difference of this compared to SQL Express?  And does it matter if SQL Express is connected as attached or detached in that respect?

I'm specially concerned with latency/lag, as my program is not typically User-activity based, but mainly controlled by algorithms and other data-input. I have an impression that SQL CE may have an advantage over SQL Server (& Express) when considering this. Is there any truth to that?

Also if any other (non-MS) databases has advantages in this area, it would be nice to also know about those options & reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Compact is a set of DLL files (a database engine), loaded by your application. SQL Server (Express) is a Windows Service, and must be reahed via a network interface. For more details see this blog post and links therein: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/01/comparison-of-sql-server-compact-4-and.html